# Given a set with 6 vertices, can you prove or disprove G is planar

Tags: graph-theory

$p,q$ prime numbers

On set $V=\{1,p,q,pq,p^2q,pq^2\}$ of verticies

Given $G(V,E)$ a undirected simple graph
We define :
$\forall x,y \ \in \ V  $
$\exists \ xy \ \in E \ \text{ iff }\ x|y$

Prove or disprove that the graph is planar .

I tried to prove and it seems it is a planer but i am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a connected planar graph with $n\ge 3$, we must have $e\le 3n-6$

$\;\;\;\;$ [https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/graphtheory-F11/planar.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Esk1233/courses/graphtheory-F11/planar.pdf)

but for the given graph, we have $n=6$ and $e=13$.

Comment: So this is the whole actual argument? I suspected it is to short to be a correct answer to this

Comment: An alternative method is to show that it has the non-planar subgraph $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: Nice alternative , didnt think about it

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis: The $K_{3,3}$ argument would make a nice alternative answer. Why not post it?

Answer (score 2):

Every element in the set $\{1,p,q\}$ divides every element in the set $\{pq,pq^2, p^2q\}$. This establishes that $G$ has a subgraph $K_{3,3}$, which is non-planar, making $G$ itself non-planar, too.

Comment: Great proof , actually i tried at first by intuition to draw but i recognized that more generalized proof is needed